# A simple datepicker in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to make a datetimepicker in a components input tag. I have implemented bootstrap-datetimpicker but when i choose date i cant get input value in the components methods(
here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ma9sgnd8/1/

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: ''
  },
  mounted: function() {

       var args = {

            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
       };
        this.$nextTick(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(args)
        });

       this.$nextTick(function() {
          $('.time-picker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT'
          })
       });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out vue listens to the `input` event of the dom node rather than monitoring the `value` of the js object (which is reasonable, because there won't be any js object until we `document.querySelector()` or so). Proof: [in the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model), it says we can use a `.lazy` modifier to *listen to `change` events instead of `input`*. So when the jQuery-based bootstrap plugin changes the input's `value` in js, vue won't detect it.

Luckily, the plugin [provides a change event](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/), so we can manually set the view-model's property when the change event fires: https://jsfiddle.net/ma9sgnd8/4/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your datepicker, if you look in console, it crashes and prob. does not update the state correctly, try the default one:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
  <input type="date" v-model="date">
  </div>
  {{date}}
</div>
```

(or external package like https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker)